# The Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{T} = \Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis

I started reading Katznelson's book on harmonic analysis. on the first page of the book gives the following about the group $\mathbb{T} = \Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{Z}$:

"The Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{T}$ can be defined by means of the folllowing identification: a function ${f}$ is integrable on $\Bbb{T}$ if the corresponding $2\pi$-periodic function, which we denote again by ${f}$ is integrable on [$0$ , $2\pi$) and we set $$\int_{\Bbb{T}}{f(t)dt}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{f(x)dx}$$
In other words, we consider [$0$ , $2\pi$) as a model for $\Bbb{T}$ and the Lebesgue measure $dt$ on $\Bbb{T}$ is the restriction of the Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb{R}$ restricted to [$0$ , $2\pi$)."

I'm having trouble understanding how $dt$ is a measure at all. I know I probably just haven't done enough measure theory to understand but i haven't found anything particularly helpful while searching for an answer. If someone could explain this to me or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The measure is $\mu(A) = \int_{A \cap [0,2\pi)} dx= \int_0^{2\pi} 1_{x \in A}dx$ for any $A$ subset of $\Bbb{R/2\pi Z}$

Comment: Oh i see, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure is the integral of 1 over the region intersected with (restricted to) $[0,2\pi)$, in other words just the integral of the indicator function of that region over $[0,2\pi)$.